# Fetch specific column in input file and apply multiply expression in adf dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the below data(semi column(;) is the delimiter).

```
abc;50;7,00;def
ghi;10;20,00;jkl
```

If my second column value 50, then I need to fetch third column value(7,00) and multiple with -1. So my third column output would be -7,00

My final output for my input file would be below.

```
abc;50;-7,00;def
ghi;10;20,00;jkl
```

I tried the below expression but it is not working.

```
iif(SecondColumn == 50, (float(ThirdColumn) * -1), float(ThirdColumn))
```

Please help how to achieve this requirement in adf dataflows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a space between `Second` and `Column`. If you copy/pasted from your code that might be the culprit.

Comment: Hi LosManos, thanks for your response.I removed the space and tried. But it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach to achieve your requirement.

Your 3rd column will be taken as a string by default in dataflow when you import the projection. So, first read the column as `float` using projection by specifying the format.

[image]

Now, you will get the data like this in data preview.

[image]

Then, take a dataflow and use the below expression.

```
iif(second==50, multiply(third,-1),third)
```

[image]

**Result in sink file:**

[image]

If you don't want to change the type using projection, keep the type as string and modify the expression like below which also gives the same result.

```
iif(second==50, multiply(toFloat(replace(third,',','')),-1),toFloat(replace(third,',','')))
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for your response. It is working fine with your solution, but my third column value is coming "-700.0". But it should come -7,00. My final output for my first row should be like below: 
 abc;50;-7,00;def.  Could you please help here to get this output.

Comment: I tried lot of ways to do that but not able to achieve it. AFAIK, in ADF we might not get the values like that using float. If your requirement is that, then simply use string functions instead of float. try this expression. `iif(second==50, iif(instr(third,'-')==0,concat('-',third),dropLeft(third, 1)),third)`
 keep the column as string in the projection. This will give the your required result https://i.imgur.com/IlJBsmC.png. You need to change it to your required type when you are using output data.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I tried this expression and it is working fine.Thank you :)